# MySQL query for selecting distinct field and then ordering by date

Tags: mysql, date, select

I would like to sort a table by date. I have multiple records for the same artist name but they have different dates

e.g.

```
ARTIST:DATE
Gerd:2011-09-28
Gerd:2011-09-01
Simon:2011-07-01
Simon:2011-10-02
Franco:2011-01-10
Franco:2011-09-15
Franco:2011-07-01
Des:2011-09-05
```

How can I extract the distinct username and show the most recent date that they had a record created on? I would also like to only show names that have more than 2 records

so in this case the results I want are

```
Simon:2011-10-02
Gerd:2011-09-28
Franco:2011-09-15
```

(I would like these to be sorted in date order)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Artist, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
FROM Artists
GROUP BY Artist
HAVING COUNT(Artist) > 2 
ORDER BY MaxDate DESC
```

Your question explicitly states "more than 2", but your example data illustrates >= 2. In any case, you can adjust the `HAVING` if/as you require:

```
HAVING COUNT(Artist) >=2
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I missed out a vital part of the query -I would also like to only show names that have more than 2 records. Any ideas? (post edited to reflect this)

Comment: @Franco: yep, use `HAVING` as in the edited answer. You say "more than 2", but your example is greater-than-or-equal to 2.